Old war movie, cat and mouse chase between 2 soldiers and finishes with leaflets dropped from a plane
I am trying to find the name of an old war movie I saw about 15-20 years ago. I only saw the last 30min - 45min of it so these details are the only ones I remember:

There were 2 soldiers, staking each other out, playing a cat and mouse chase
I think one of the soldiers was Japanese (I could be wrong tho)
The soldiers didn't speak, so the movie (the part I saw) was pretty silent
The setting from what I can remember is on the ground in the middle of nowhere, with old ? barnyards.
At the end, leaflets were dropped by a plane to indicate the end of the war
Both soldiers are reluctant to emerge from hiding in fear their enemy will shoot them.
Eventually, both soldiers emerge from hiding. They both survive.

I thought it could have been The Last Bullet but I think it was made even earlier than this (maybe the 80's). Also not Kukushka.

It is indeed "The Last Bullet" (1995):
Near the end of the movie there is a small plane dropping leaflets indicating the war is over. Full movie is on Youtube here (in Russian):



Ca. at the 1:15:37 mark comes the plane, drops the leaflets, Japanese soldier catches one of the leaflets and reads it.  
Regarding the other answer, there are no leaflets being dropped from a plane at the end of "Hell in the Pacific", the two soldiers do not survive (at least in the theatrical version), and they do not have firearms, they do not shoot at each other, as far as I can remember. 

It sounds like "Hell In The Pacific" with Lee Marvin, although I don't remember the leaflets being dropped.

During World War II, an American pilot and a marooned Japanese navy
  captain are deserted on a small uninhabited island in the Pacific
  Ocean. There, they must cease their hostility and cooperate if they
  want to survive, but will they?




